# How can i add a counter badge to a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I add a counter badge to a widget? Like in [this screenshot](http://www.mightygrocery.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Widget-small-180x300.png)

`Google Reader` also has a widget with counter.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? A home screen widget can have a layout, and that layout can contain an ImageView and a TextView.

You will then create a background service that is checking how many messages there are e.g. every 15 minutes, and then update the widget.

Comment: Yes of course, but i wnat to know if a standard counter badge exists or if i have to add my own with imageview and textview.
I mean the counter badge like in the notification bar. There is no need to create a imageview and textview to display the counter.

Comment: I have not seen a standard widget for that.