# Android widget for application icon badges

Tags: android, icons, badge

help me how to add a counter badge to application icon.
I am in really need of this.
I searched and analyses only one way to install widget but could not find widget for application icon for badges.

[Add a Counter Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123765/how-can-i-add-a-counter-badge-to-a-widget)

[Like this](http://www.mightygrocery.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Widget-small-180x300.png)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569695/android-is-it-possible-to-update-a-imageview-imagebutton-with-a-number-to-show

Comment: Hey ccheneson
Thank you for this.
Do you have any test project for application widgets ?

Comment: No, but all the required code is in the link above. There is also an Actvity test to test the count as nornally you can only update a widget once every 30 min.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot for your precious Help !!

Comment: Hey ccheneson
Mostly i got it but one thing is it compulsary to add AppWidgetProviderInfo and AppWidgetProvider class to my code.

and where your test activity exist ...Is it main activity ?

Comment: The test activity is there just to check that the value of the badge is updated. If you want to create an Widget, then Yes, AppWidgetProvider is compulsary (dunno about AppWidgetProviderInfo, long time I havent worked with Android) . I ll see at home if I still have the code to test the widget itself